# Access windows by name

Tags: wpf, window, find

I am quite new to WPF, coming from the Delphi world. I solved the problem below (albeit painfully) in the Delphi world, and hope there is a more elegant solution in the WPF world.

I need to read in an XML file containing a menu "tree", which has the window names in it as well as the menu prompts, and then be able to "show" a window based on having its name.

For example, a segment of the menu, with two choices, might have XML like this:

```
<MenuLeaf>
  <Header>Product information</Header>
  <MenuLine>    
    <Prompt>Product Master File</Prompt>
    <WindowName>Products.xaml</WindowName>
  </MenuLine>
  <MenuLine>    
    <Prompt>Inventory Data</Prompt>
    <WindowName>Inventory.xaml</WindowName>
  </MenuLine>
</MenuLeaf>
```

So when the user makes the "Inventory Data" choice, I will know that I want to do a "show" of the window Inventory.xaml ..... but I only have the literal string "Inventory.xaml".

I will have hundreds of these forms, and the XML file can vary from time to time - so it's not effective for me to have the standard code of

```
Dim window as New Inventory
window.Show
```

for each of the several hundred windows.

What I need is something that does

```
Dim window as New {go out and find the Inventory file with name Inventory.xaml}
window.Show
```

I have searched endlessly for this with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path to solution is to use Reflection, which will allow you to dynamically find/invoke your classes. Say your Namespace is MyNs, then you must have a 'Products' Class within it that correspond to the 'Products.xaml' file. To find it, use MyFoundType = MyNs.GetType("Products")
Then get default (or other if you like) constructor for this type :   MyFoundType.GetConstructor(). Then invoke the constructor (with arguments if needed) --> you now have your window as an Object.
Cast it to a window and call its Show method, and you're done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx

Comment: I agree with this; however you should be able to use Activator.CreateInstance(type); instead of hassling with finding the method.  Something like:   var win = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(<Get Assembly>.GetType(<TypeName>);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the XamlReader object, which parses XAML at run-time and creates the object.

```
var rdr = XmlReader.Create(File.Open("Inventory.xaml"));
var window = XamlReader.Load(rdr) as Window;
window.Show();
```

The `XamlReader.Load` will return whatever the actual top-level element in the XAML specifies; if it's a `Window` you can just `.Show` it. If it's something else, you'll need a container to place it in. For example, you might have a `Window` with a `Border` element in it and do:

```
var control = XamlReader.Load(rdr) as UserControl;
var window = new MyHostWindow();
window.ContentBorder.Child = control;
```

If you don't actually know the type of element in your XAML you can usually use `FrameworkElement`, which is the base class for all the visual elements, though you won't get Window-specific behavior from that.

Comment: how would you do if constructor of window has parameter(s) ?

Comment: He said he had a XAML file that contained the window he needs. As long as it's a valid XAML file, XamlReader will construct it. XALM elements have to have a parameterless constructor and public properties, since that's how XAML works.

If you wanted to construct a visual element that required parameters in the constructor, you couldn't do it in XAML and XamlReader would not work.